# Conversion from string "Large" to type 'Double' is not valid

Tags: vb.net

So im trying to get my code to work which is meant to display a price dependant on the size and amount however when i try to run the code and get the price I get the error

Conversion from string "Large" to type 'Double' is not valid.

when I click my price button.

```
Dim large As Integer
Dim total As Integer

Private Sub PictureBox1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.Click
End Sub

Private Sub PreviewButton_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles PreviewButton.Click
    PictureBox1.Image = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile _
      ("H:\My Pictures\" + ColourComboBox.SelectedItem + "Tshirt.PNG")

    PictureBox1.ClientSize = New Size(200, 200)
    PictureBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage

    str = "The colour chosen is " & ColourComboBox.SelectedItem _
        & vbCrLf & " and the size chosen is " & SizeComboBox.SelectedItem

End Sub

Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

End Sub

Private Sub SizeComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles SizeComboBox.SelectedIndexChanged
    small = 10
    medium = 12
    large = 15

End Sub
Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnbuy.Click
    total = SizeComboBox.SelectedItem * AmountComboBox.SelectedItem
    MessageBox.Show(total)
End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: which line is giving error

Comment: Turn `Option Strict On`... I suspect it may be this line `total = SizeComboBox.SelectedItem * AmountComboBox.SelectedItem`, can you show us how both of these combobox's are filled? I bet your trying to multiply strings and this will not work...

Comment: The error message is actually fairly self-explanatory …

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like this error message:

> Conversion from string "Large" to type 'Double' is not valid.

Occurs at this line (`Button2_Click()` sub):

```
total = SizeComboBox.SelectedItem * AmountComboBox.SelectedItem
```

Both selected items seems to be String values, and one of them equals `"Large"`. Maybe you should fix the way you retrieve the integer value assigned to "Large" item.

VB.NET implicitely converts Strings to Integer - only if Option Strict is not enabled, which is **strongly** discouraged (as pointed out by Konrad Rudolph) - but it fails here, since the value doesn't represent an Integer.

Comment: “VB.NET implicitely converts Strings to Integer” — only if `Option Strict` is not enabled, which is **strongly** discouraged (I have no idea why Microsoft refuses to change this offensively stupid default).

Comment: @KonradRudolph, I added your comment (and attributed).

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you use a NumericUpDown for the Amount (quantity) input. You can set the minimum and maximum values.

```
Private Sub SizeComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles SizeComboBox.SelectedIndexChanged
    small = 10
    medium = 12
    large = 15
End Sub
```

Your code above really does nothing except the value of your form level variables. The text in the combobox is not related to these variables.

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    ComboBox1.Items.Add("small")
    ComboBox1.Items.Add("medium")
    ComboBox1.Items.Add("large")
End Sub
```

I added the items to the combobox in Form.Load but this can be done at design time.

```
Private ProductSize As Decimal = 0

Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
    Select Case ComboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString
        Case "small"
            ProductSize = 10
        Case "medium"
            ProductSize = 12
        Case "large"
            ProductSize = 15
        Case Else
            MessageBox.Show("Please make a size selection.")
    End Select
End Sub
```

Here we have added a form level variable to hold the selected size.

Finally the arithmetic is done and the result displayed. When .ToString("C") is called on the Decimal Total the C tells it to display the result as currency.

```
Private Sub Button4_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button4.Click
    Dim Total = ProductSize * NumericUpDown1.Value
    MessageBox.Show(Total.ToString("C"))
End Sub
```